# NSURL and URL Validity

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsurl

I'm using a URL from an API where a search term is surrounded by quotation marks. For example:
`http://www.example.com/searchterm="search"`.

However, because of the quotation marks, my NSURL (generated by URLWithString) is nil due to an invalid URL. Is there a way around this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place a backslash before the quotation mark, or the URL encoded value **`%22`**:

`http://www.example.com/searchterm=\"search\"`

`http://www.example.com/searchterm=%22search%22`

or you can remove the quotations before using it as an NSURL.

```
NSString * searchUrl = @"http://www.example.com/searchterm=\"search\"";
searchUrl = 
  [searchUrl stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""]; // something to this effect, not tested.
```

Then you can go about your normal NSURL call:

```
[NSURL URLWithString: searchUrl];
```

Comment: I did this. That's how I got my initial string. But then I tried `NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:URLString];` and it returned nil (even though URLString is correct)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
#define SAFARI_SEARCH_URL_FORMAT @"http://search/search?q=\"%@\""
mySearchBar.text =@"hello";
NSString * tempstr = [NSString stringWithFormat:SAFARI_SEARCH_URL_FORMAT, mySearchBar.text];

    NSURL *an1Url = [[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[tempstr stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
] autorelease];
NSLog(@"--(%@)--",an1Url);
```

`an1Url` will not be nil